# Magento2 integration with odoo

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento-connect, magento-connect-manager

I am new with magento and odoo. I want to use magento2 for frontend and odoo for backend. I have serached all over google and youtube.

> how to integrate magento2 and odoo ?

But I did not get any  **good** tutorial or installation guide.

Can you provide me some tutorial or guide ?

I am using `ubuntu server 16.04 lts (only cli).`

Running on `windows machine 192.168.0.50 server ip.`

Answer (score 2):

Do you try use [Official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html).

Odoo  connector currently do not support Magento 2. See: https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/magentoerpconnect/

> Support Magento 1.7+ (not 2.x), the support of earlier versions should
>   be easy to add, the connector framework being designed to handle
>   multiple versions with ease.

See https://github.com/OCA/connector-magento/issues/211 to track process of development version for m2

Comment: i did not find any connector there.

Comment: what i do now please help me ? i didnot find any help in provided link

Comment: Maybe you ask for installation guide for oddo connector?

Comment: i have odoo v9 .

Comment: so i cannot connect magento2 and odoo v9 yet ?

Comment: Yes, you cannot connect magento2 and odoo v9 yet

Comment: isnt there any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Odoo - Magento 2 Connector which will help you to integrate your Magento 2 with Odoo V9.

1. Configure multiple magento globals together in single odoo
2. Dashboard
3. Import customer groups, customers, product categories, Products, product Images, Attributes, Attributes Options, Attribute sets, Attribute  groups From Magento 2 to Odoo.
4. Payment Method configuration
5. Manage multi currency orders.
6. Tax configuration
7. Product stock Export configuration (actual and fixed)
   8  Magento 2 instance wise auto schedule Jobs configuration and setup
8. Log details for every transaction between Odoo and Magento 2
9. Sales & Invoice Analysis Report
10. Export attributes, attributes option, attribute groups, attribute sets, product category, products and product images from Odoo to Magento 2.
11. Product Export with custom attributes. (create, update and delete in magento)
12. Export multiple product in with multiple website link
13. Export multiple product image (create, update and delete in magento)
14. Import order with payment
15. Import order with shipment
16. Export shipment (partial and complete shipment)
17. Export shipment with tracking number
18. Export Customer invoice
19. Auto Workflow Configuration
20. Auto Register Payment

For more information you can visit : [Odoo - Magento 2 Connector](https://shop.emiprotechnologies.com/odoo-magento-2-connector.html)